# check if an element is a neighbor and then create a new column

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe which consists of the five columns "ID", "Name", "pos_x", "pos_y" and "Volume", something like this:

```
ID | Name | pos_x | pos_y | volume
1  |  A   |  1    |  1.5  |  10
2  |  A   |  3.5  |  3    |   6
3  |  A   |  4    |  4    |   8
4  |  A   |  4.5  |  4.5  |   9
5  |  A   |  5    |  6    |  10
1  |  B   |  1.2  |  1.2  |   4
3  |  B   |  4.3  |  4.4  |   8
4  |  B   |  4.5  |  4.2  |   7
2  |  C   |  3    |  3.3  |   9
3  |  C   |  4.2  |  4.1  |  10
```

I would now like to create a new column in the dataframe ("volume_avg") in which the average of the volume of all ID`s is calculated, which lie within a radius of 2.5 mm to the respective ID.

My idea was to first run through each ID for each name (because the name + ID is the primary key) and then look at the position x and y for each ID. With an if loop I would then check if the ID is a neighbor or not.

So the conditions would be:

if pos_x (current ID) < pos_x (all other IDs) - 2.5 OR > pos_x (all other IDs) + 2.5

else if pos_y (current ID) < pos_y (all other IDs) - 2.5  OR > pos_y (all other IDs) + 2.5

then calculate sum(volume)/count(ID's)

otherwise nothing

Unfortunately I don't know how to write these considerations in a python code....
I would be glad if you can help me. Thanks a lot.

David

Comment: just to be clear instead of sum(height) you meant sum(volume) right?

Comment: @David14 do you want the average to be ***within*** a `Name` value or across all `Name`s? E.g. would the average volume for a `df['Name']=='A'` include the row `1 | B | 1.2 | 1.2 | 4` in the average or exclude ?

Comment: @Anthony1223 yes you are right. i have corrected it

Comment: @LucasRoberts No the average should only be within a name value. The row 1 | B | 1.2 | 1.2 | 4 should therefore be excluded from the average for df['Name']=='A'.

Comment: @Anthony1223 should the boolean in the if/else be written with an `or` rather than `and` ? If I'm interpreting correctly as is currently written the two conditions ***cannot*** occur at the same time.

Comment: @LucasRoberts yes you are absolutely right. it should be written with an or.

Comment: @David14 great, take a look at the example code I provided, if that's correct, consider marking the problem correct so it is labeled correctly in the system. If not let me know what I misunderstood.

Comment: @LucasRoberts Thank you so much! I'll check the code and let you know. 
I don't know if it has a big impact, but the original dataset is about 50,000 rows with 20 columns

Comment: @David14 In terms of speed the metrics to look at are the lengths of the groups of `Name` not the entire row count. If runtime is essential consider using an R-tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree to accelerate the lookup. You'd need to build one for each unique value of `Name` (each group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting the conditions in the if and the else portion to be rectangular limits on the `(x,y)` coordinates. If this is incorrect please let me know and I can adjust the logic in the if/else.

```
import pandas as pd

# create the structure of example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A', 1, 1.5, 10],
                   [2, 'A', 3.5, 3, 6],
                   [3, 'A', 4, 4, 8],
                   [4, 'A', 4.5, 4.5, 9],
                   [5 ,'A' , 5 , 6 , 10],
                   [1 ,'B' , 1.2 , 1.2 , 4],
                   [3 ,'B' , 4.3 , 4.4 , 8],
                   [4 ,'B' , 4.5 , 4.2 , 7],
                   [2 ,'C' , 3 , 3.3 , 9],
                   [3 ,'C' , 4.2 , 4.1 , 10],
                   ],
                  columns=['ID', 'Name', 'pos_x', 'pos_y', 'volume'])

# create volume average with rows that meet criterion
volume_avgs = []
for g, grouper in df.groupby('Name'):
    for base_row in grouper.iterrows():
        v_sum = 0
        v_count = 0
        for row in grouper.iterrows():
            if row[1].ID == base_row[1].ID: # skip the item itself
                continue
            elif abs(row[1].pos_x - base_row[1].pos_x) < 2.5 or abs(row[1].pos_y - base_row[1].pos_y) < 2.5:
                 v_sum += row[1].volume
                 v_count += 1
        volume_avgs.append([base_row[1].ID, g, v_sum / v_count if v_count > 0 else 0, v_count])

df_vol_avgs = pd.DataFrame(volume_avgs, columns=['ID', 'Name', 'volume_avg', 'volume_count'])

merged_df = df.merge(df_vol_avgs, on=['ID', 'Name'])
merged_df
```

Be aware that if the actual data are large this probably won't scale very well. Particularly to groups with a lot of data because of the double for loop. Also if you want a `None` or `Nan` if the total number of nearby points to average is 0 you can change the if/else from

```
v_sum / v_count if v_count > 0 else 0
```

to

```
v_sum / v_count if v_count > 0 else None
```

for the `None` case and similarly for `Nan`, say using `numpy.nan`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a method that works but, however, isn't the cleanest and can probably be optimized in many ways.

First, we import pandas and create the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
ID = [1,2,3,4,5,1,3,4,2,3]
name = ["A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"]
pos_x = [1,3.5,4,4.5,5,1.2,4.3,4.5,3,4.2]
pos_y = [1.5,3,4,4.5,6,1.2,4.4,4.2,3.3,4.1]
volume = [10,6,8,9,10,4,8,7,9,10]
dict = {"ID": ID, "name": name, "pos_x":pos_x, "pos_y":pos_y,"volume":volume}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Then, we declare an empty list to store our results and iterate over the dataframe:

```
values = []
for i in df.itertuples():
    posX = i.pos_x
    posY = i.pos_y
    counter = 0
    volume_counter = 0
    for j in df.itertuples():
        if i == j:
            pass
        elif abs(j.pos_x - posX) <= 2.5 and abs(j.pos_y - posY) <= 2.5:
            counter += 1
            volume_counter += j.volume
        else:
            pass
    values.append(round(volume_counter/counter,2))
```

For each row of the dataframe, we get the x and y position. We also set  counter and volume_counter to 0. Counter counts how many items fulfill the condition of being within 2.5 mm from other positions, and volume_counter adds up the volumes of the rows that fulfill the condition.

Then, we iterate again for every row in the dataframe. The first if clause discards the value if it is itself (if you want to include the volume of every object in the dataframe you can simply delete this clause), the elif clause checks if x_pos and y_pos are within an absolute distance of 2.5 mm.

Finally, we append the total volume divided by the number of items (I've also rounded up the result to 2 decimal places, but you can also remove it if you want more decimals). This gives us the following list:

```
[6.33, 8.12, 8.43, 8.29, 8.4, 8.33, 8.43, 8.57, 7.75, 8.14]
```

We can therefore join the calculated list to the original dataframe.

```
df["volume_avg"] = values
df
```

The output is as follows:

```
   ID name pos_x  pos_y  volume volume_avg
0   1   A   1.0     1.5     10  6.33
1   2   A   3.5     3.0     6   8.12
2   3   A   4.0     4.0     8   8.43
3   4   A   4.5     4.5     9   8.29
4   5   A   5.0     6.0     10  8.40
5   1   B   1.2     1.2     4   8.33
6   3   B   4.3     4.4     8   8.43
7   4   B   4.5     4.2     7   8.57
8   2   C   3.0     3.3     9   7.75
9   3   C   4.2     4.1     10  8.14
```

I hope this helps. I am sure that there are cleaner ways to do this, and I'd also appreciate feedback on the proposed solution!

Comment: thank you very much. The code works perfectly. Your explanations also help me understand the code very well.

but I am not sure if the calculation of the average is correct. Does the code consider the average should be calculated within a name? 
e.g. Name == 'A' :
of ID == 1 only ID == 2 is the direct neighbor. So the average should be (10+6)/2. or am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. Do you mean that for row 0 only row 1 (ID 2, name a, volume 6) should be considered and not all indices that are within 2.5 mm of  pos_x AND pos_y? Currently the code calculates the average volume for ALL rows (that are within 2.5 mm of pos_x AND pos_y)

Comment: yes that is exactly what I mean. So that you look at the IDs for the names individually.
e.g. for ID 1 at name 'a' you would then only look at the volumes of the rows that are within 2.5mm in x and 2.5mm in y that have the name 'A' and not all rows. I hope you understand what I mean.